# How to use asterisks in awk if statment

Tags: awk, aix

I have a scenario where I need to print a line, but using an awk if to search for a number the is appened with a double colon with more numbers:

See below example:

```
test1 test2 37:375003 test3 test4
test1 test2 38:375004 test3 test4
test1 test2 39:375005 test3 test4
test1 test2 40:375006 test3 test4
test1 test2 41:375007 test3 test4
```

What I want to achieve is using the command like below:

```
cat test_out.txt | awk "{if ($3 == 37~/\:*/ ) print $0;}"
```

The above should give me the below line:

```
test1 test2 37:375003 test3 test4
```

Getting the syntax error below:

```
Syntax Error The source line is 1.
The error context is
             {if ( >>>  == <<<
awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `~` binary operator whose syntax is:

```
string ~ regexp
```

To match a string against a regular expression, so:

```bash
<test_out.txt awk '$3 ~ /^37:[[:digit:]]+$/'
```

To print the records (`{print}`, short for `{print $0}` being the default action) whose third field matches the `^37:[[:digit:]]+$` extended regexp.

In ERE syntax:

- `^` matches at the start of the subject
- `[...]`: matches any character or collating element in the set.
- `[:digit:]` in the set above means any character classified as decimal digit in the locale (on most systems, that's limited to 0123456789). Change to `0123456789` in `mawk` which doesn't support those POSIX character classes or if you don't want to match other decimal digits. `0-9` would also work in `mawk` but could also match on other characters in some `awk` implementations.
- `+` is for one-or-more of the preceding thing. So here one-or-more digits
- `$` matches at the end of the subject.

If you don't care whether the part after `37:` is made of digits or not, then the regexp is just `^37:` (`37:` at the start of the subject).

Another approach would be:

```bash
<test_out.txt awk '$3 + 0 == 37'
```

Where the `+ 0` numeric operation forces `awk` to try and convert `$3` to a number, ignoring anything past the initial number. Then that would match on `37:anything`, but also `37.0;whatever`¹, `3.7e+1`¹, possibly `0x25#xxx` with some `awk` implementations, `+37+38`... Using `+$3 == 37` though standard, doesn't work with some `awk` implementations.

For the value (here `37`) to come from a shell variable, you could construct the regexp in the shell and pass it to `awk` via an `ENVIRON`ment variable:

```bash
var=37
ERE='^'$var':[[:digit:]]+$' <test_out.txt awk '$3 ~ ENVIRON["ERE"]'
```

Or make an `awk` `v`ariable out of the shell variable²:

```bash
var=37
<test_out.txt awk -v n="$var" '$3 ~ "^" n ":[[:digit:]]+"'
```

Avoid expanding the shell variable into the `awk` code as in:

```
<test_out.txt awk '$3 ~ /^'"$var"':[[:digit:]]+$/'
```

as that typically introduces command injection vulnerabilities (the worst type of vulnerability).

Some comments on your attempt:

- as already [noted by @RudyC](/a/722332), you used double quotes around your awk code. Shells perform parameter expansion inside those, so the `$3` would be expanded to the value of the third argument to the shell script, and `$0` to the name of the script.
- `$3 == 37 ~ /\:*/`. [`==` has higher precedence than `~`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html#tab41). So that's `($3 == 37) ~ /\:*/`. So that's matching the `\:*` regexp against the result of that comparison (1 or 0 depending on whether `$3` is 37 or not)
- `\:*` as a regexp is unspecified as `\:` is unspecified. To match a literal `:`, it's `:` alone. `:*` would be 0 or more `:`s so match on anything since any string contains at least 0 `:`s. `*` in regexps matches on 0 or more of the previous thing. You may be confusing it with the `*` of shell wildcards that matches 0 or more characters. In regexps, 0 or more characters is `.*`, `.` being the operator to match a single character.
- `awk` statements are of the form `condition {action}`, where either *condition* or *action* can be omitted. In your case, you omitted the *condition* and used `if` in the *action*, and used `{print $0}` which happens to be the default *action*. While that works, that will look very `awk`ward to `awk` users.
- you used `cat` to con`cat`enate a single file which hardly makes sense. The shell can open the file by itself to make it the stdin of `awk` using redirection which saves a process and the need to shove the contents through a pipe. You could also pass the file name as argument to `awk` which can also open it by itself.

---

<sup>¹ assuming the decimal radix character is `.` and not `,` in the locale, at least with some `awk` implementations such as GNU `awk` in POSIX mode.</sup>

<sup>² beware that `-v` mangles backslashes, so using `ENVIRON` is safer in the general case.</sup>

Comment: How can I use a variable in place holder like below:
     VAL1=37
     awk '$5 ~ /^"'"$VAL1"'":[[:digit:]]+$/' test_out.txt

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is using the double quotes `"` for the `awk` script which makes the shell expand `$3` to whatever the shell has, here presumably the empty string. Use single quotes `'` or a file instead.

Then, of course, use the right regex for your task, as given in other answers.